# Having problems testing my application on a blackberry 10 simulator

Tags: blackberry, sdk, blackberry-webworks

After building and installing on the `blackberry 10 webworks sdk,` 
I get the following error :

```
fs.js:418
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:418:11)
    at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:206:6)
    at _self.findConnectedSimulator (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\target-utils.js:209:12)
    at Object.async.series.ip (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\run-utils.js:48:17)
    at C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:561:25
    at iterate (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:131:13)
    at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:147:9)
    at Object.async.series (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:560:19)
    at Object.getTargetName (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\run-utils.js:45:15)
    at fn (C:\TestApps\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:579:34)
```